# Элементарная программа неожиданно завершилась

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Возникла необходимость изучить Qt.
Скачал с официального сайта онлайн инсталлятор и выполнил установку *Qt Creator 4.1.0.*
В системе стоит *VS2015* (в которой установлен модуль для С++ и он рабочий).
Запустил *Qt Creator*, создал *Desktop* приложение. Удалил файлы *mainWindow*. Оставил только файл *main.cpp*.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel lbl("dsdsd");

    lbl.show();

    return a.exec();
 }
```

После сборки и запуска пишет ошибку:

> Программа неожиданно завершилась.

[image: Главное окно проекта]

Выбранная сборка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки запуска сборки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компилятор используется *MSVC2015_64bit*

*.pro* файл:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = prj1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS  +=
```

Comment: Покажите код в файле `.pro`, может там что-то не так после удаления файлов

Comment: добавил! смотрите в основной теме.

Comment: А давайте без лишнего творчества - создайте шаблонный проект, запустите и посмотрите. Работает?

Comment: У меня приведенный код запустился с сообщением в дебаге `setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 28x13+640+280 on QWidgetWindow/'QLabelClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  124x13+640+280 (frame: 8, 31, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215)`. У меня MinGW. Попробуйте на чистом проекте без дополнительных удалений

Comment: А папки release/debug удалили? Они появляются в папке уровнем выше проекта

Comment: воот как папки удалил все завелось)))

Comment: это всегда так надо делать, удалять release/debug папки сразу после первой неудачной сборки проекта?

Comment: Еще ребят вопрос как мне отладчик добавить? Сейчас ругается что его нету.

Comment: так как используется студия, то нужно скачать CDB и прописать http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-engines.html

Answer (score 1):

- Создовая шаблонное консольное приложение, не нужно создовать
  приложение с окнами.
- Для успешной сборки и дальнейшей работы нужно
  перейти на каталог выше и удалить кактлоги release/debug.

Answer (score 0):

`QLabel` следует попробовать поместить в `QWidget` и выполнить `widget->show()`